# How to download mongo database from website hosted at origin.meteor.com

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Is it possible to download the complete mongo db from an app hosted on meteor's servers in order to transfer it to Heroku, other than just to download each Collection individually?

Comment: Do you get a Console at the metro's server to manage Mongo? Or You can just look for the ways to dump data wrt Metro

Comment: @ShivKumarGanesh Not as far as I can see - at least, it's not documented

Comment: Which technology are you using other than mongoDB as in the programming language. Since from there itself you can issue a command to dump data

Comment: Meteor.js - what command would you type in the mongo shell if you had access?

Comment: Just check my reply. It works for me. I guess it would do for you too. Let me know if it does!!

Comment: @Swadq: If you can connect to the meteor-hosted MongoDB instance from the `mongo` shell, then your best option for dumping the complete database would be to use [`mongodump`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) to create a backup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a quick script for this, [meteor-download](https://github.com/AlexeyMK/meteor-download).  Easy as `./download.sh origin.meteor.com`

Answer (score 1):

Better go with a tool called UMongo

http://edgytech.com/umongo/

It comes in all flavours and is absolutely free. (For Mac Linux and Windows)
I checked it out a moment ago with a remote MongoDB, you need to enter the 
credentials as well as the IP and Port and you are done. You would see the 
Databases on the right with collections mentioned. You can select any one
database and navigate to the top right. There you would find an option called Collections
where you can find the export option. Hope this solves your problem.

[image]

The software is easy to install. Just download and on terminal navigate to the directory and
type

`java -jar umongo.jar`

Note:I am using Ubuntu13.04